# sqlcmd script with spaces in filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, sqlcmd

I have a simple `SQLCMD` script that includes some lines like this:

```
/* Load data into Exampletable */
BULK INSERT dbo.Example
    /* NOTE: I've tried single AND double quotes here. */
    FROM "C:\Example Filepath\test.csv"
    WITH 
    (
            /* skip the first row containing column names */
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            /* specify how fields are separated */
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
            /* specify how lines end */
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    )
```

When I run it on the command line, I get an error like this:

`Sqlcmd: 'C:\Example': Invalid filename.`

I think that having a space in the path is causing the path to be cut off, but I can't figure out a syntax that works. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message sounds like sqlcmd cannot find the .sql file.

Try `sqlcmd "c:\example filepath\test.sql"` from the command prompt.

Strings are quoted with single quotes in TSQL, with double quotes in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Surround the path with single quotes like:

```
'C:\Example Filepath\test.csv'
```

Comment: @SuperNES I have just tested it with single quotes and works fine. Maybe your file does not exists or you do not have permissions. Check also here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.90).aspx