# I am not able to upload file in my project

Tags: sql, tomcat, tomcat7

I am working on my project and trying to upload file,,

the exception is coming like this

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\webapps\multicloud\temp\C:\eula.1028.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

You have white space in your file path, so enclose it in quotes (assuming you're working in SQL from your tags) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726394/sqlcmd-script-with-spaces-in-filename)

"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\multicloud\temp\C:\eula.1028.txt"

Comment: i am giving the path via browse not entering it manually. do i have to make a specific place from where i can upload?

Comment: I am trying to edit an old project and error is coming link this